# How can CSS translate elements away from one point?

Tags: css, css-transitions, instagram

I'm trying to emulate a special effect of Instagram with CSS. In Instagram, clicking on a group of photos will make each photo grow and fly away from their original position.

[image: Instagram]

Currently, I only know how to do the growing part. I don't know how to make them `translate` starting from their original point.

**HTML**

```
<div id="photoSet">
   <img src="1.jpg" />
   <img src="2.jpg" />
   <img src="3.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@-moz-keyframes fly {
    from {
       -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    to {
       -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}

img {
   -moz-animation: fly 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you'll want to animate the `left` and `top` properties. The unfortunate piece of this is that you'll need to have one class/selector for each item you're planning to transition, along with a separate. You can then set `transition: left 0.2s, top 0.2s;` for the general selector. Just change the className of each to invoke the transition:

```
.photo { 
  transition: left 0.2s, top 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.photo.photo1 { left: 0; top: 0; }
.photo.photo2 { left: 50px; top: 0; }
.photo.photo3 { left: 100px; top: 0; }
/* etc */
.photo.photo6 { left: 100px; top: 50px; }
```

There is a downside to this, which is that some rendering engines don't *actually* hardware accelerate left/top transitions.